# How to select every two elements alternating?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select every two rows and alternate and repeat in that pattern.  How can I do this using CSS?

For example....

Blue Rows:
1,2,5,6,9,10

Red Rows:
3,4,7,8

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}
li:nth-of-type(odd){
  background-color:blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to add a key point, sorry!  This repetition will be used in an ng-repeat of unknown length so it could go on forever.  So i won't be able to explicity type by every 2 in the css.

Comment: Your edit seems irrelevant - the answers below will still alternate every 2 no matter how many elements there are. What ng-repeat scenario does that not cover?

Comment: I misread one of the comments.  Thought it was suggesting hard coding them up to 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logical rules for doing this are the following.

- Select every fourth, and the next one. Color that in red.
- Select every fourth and then move two ahead, and the next one. Color that in blue.

"Move to the next one" can be done by using the `+` combinator (next sibling).

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}
li:nth-of-type(4n+3), li:nth-of-type(4n+3) + * {
  background-color:blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(4n+1), li:nth-of-type(4n+1) + * {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul
```

Or, as Hamms suggested in the comments section below, you can use `4n+1` and `4n+2` for blue; and `4n+3` and `4n` for red.

Comment: Might be conceptually simpler to just do `(4n+1), (4n+2)` and `(4n+3), (4n)`

Comment: I forgot to mention, this will be used in an ng-repeat for unknown amount of elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-repeat - length of the list no matter.
https://jsbin.com/vizacewixe/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<style>
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}
li:nth-of-type(4n+1), li:nth-of-type(4n+2){
  background-color:blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(4n+3), li:nth-of-type(4n+4){
  background-color:red;
}

</style>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can combine the selectors with a comma that have the same style.

Answer (score 0):

It is more simple with `li:nth-child(4n)` and `li:nth-child(4n-1)` selectors. check the below code.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}
li{
  background-color:blue;
}
li:nth-child(4n),
li:nth-child(4n-1){
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
</ul>
```