# How to color every four elements alternating in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need make background color, for every four alternative elements via CSS. How could I achieve this?

I found a solution for alternative two elements, but i am not understanding how to make it in four elements.
Here is found for every two elements:-

[How to select every two elements alternating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763462/how-to-select-every-two-elements-alternating)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913095

Answer (score 1):

```
li:nth-of-type(4n) {
    color: red;
}
```

Update : Selecting group of four

```
li:nth-of-type(8n+1),
li:nth-of-type(8n+2),
li:nth-of-type(8n+3),
li:nth-of-type(8n+4)
{
    color: red;
}

li:nth-of-type(8n+5),
li:nth-of-type(8n+6),
li:nth-of-type(8n+7),
li:nth-of-type(8n+8)
{
    color: blue;
}
```

See this pen [updated ]
https://codepen.io/prny/pen/GarEMK

More about here in W3S https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: Its only selecting every fourth element, i need to select every four element, like in link that i shared its selecting every two elements.

Comment: please clarify in a list of 1 to 20 which all you want to select

Comment: 1 to 23 
1,2,3,4 ->red
5,6,7,8 ->blue

9,10,11,12 ->red
13,14,15,16 -> blue

16,17,18,19, -> red
20,21,22,23, ->blue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55913237/1273882 This is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @AnkushJain Yes, this is it, Thank You So Much.